# Rspec test returns 'should has'.

Tags: rspec2, rspec-rails

I am using rspec 2.8.o with rails 3.2.1 and Capybara 1.1.2

My rspec tests return 'should has' ... but should'nt that be 'should have'?

Just a thought .... I saw a discussion about this a while back but I cannot find it and so I wonder if someone out there knows of a solution such that the tests return ' should have '.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well has and have are two different marchers, which are you calling?